# Call the given url in newtab on button click in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

Here is my code. I need to get the google map from current location to given location. it will not go the initialize() function. What is the mistake here and what i have to change for getting map. The map will be open in a new tab.

```
$(document).on("click", "#gotoMap", function () {

    var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0857487, -80.2153016);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: '//d2g29cya9iq7ip.cloudfront.net/content/images/company/LocationMarker.png'
    });
    function LoadMAP() {
        marker.setPosition(currentLocation);
        map.setCenter(currentLocation);
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
    function initialize() {

        var longitude = $("#maplocation").data('longitude');
        var latitude = $("#maplocation").data('latitude');
        var website = $("#maplocation").data('website');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: longitude, lng: latitude },
            zoom: 8
        };
        $(".location").attr("target", "_blank");
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


})
```

///**************////
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

The above code will not call the initialize method. So first want to call the initialize method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to call initialize method or $(".location").attr("target", "_blank");  call this code after loading the DOM element having the class ".location".

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. i removed the code $(".location").attr("target", "_blank"); This s for new tab. Even though, it is not triggering the iniitialize() method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate map on gotomap button click, you do not need  `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);`

Just call `initialize()` and put functions outside of click event;

Comment: I am getting this error. I changed my code as like you said. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null.

Comment: I referred these two scripts ::<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true"></script>

Comment: i didnt use that offsetWidth. But it shows like that. it throws error from currentLocation definition

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the initialize() function after complete loading of the page,
that is on onDeviceReady function such as

`$(document).ready(function() { 
initialize();
 });`

Hope this will help you to solve your issue.